# After moving to the U.S., how much tax do I have to pay for my income in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, india, dtaa

I moved to the U.S. on 8th Oct. I will be having total income of around $11,500 in these 3 months.

Currently the tax is being deducted from my income which includes state tax/federal tax/SSN tax/Medicare tax.

Will all the tax be refunded to me?

And as I have also stayed more than 181 days in India during the year, do I need to pay tax on this income in India?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To get a reasonable approximation, we'd need to know more about your circumstances.  For instance, are you single or married, have kids or other dependents, deductible expenses, &c?  But short answer is that SS/medicare doesn't get refunded.  You may or may not get some of the federal income tax back (most W2 earners do), but not much.  State tax depends on the state.  WRT Indian tax, I don't know specifics, but most countries have tax treaties so that you'd pay only if the other county has a higher tax rate, and then only the difference.

Comment: It would also be useful to tell us what your _visa_ status and citizenship status is. It might be that you will be considered to be a nonresident alien for 2016, or you might be considered to be a resident alien (e.g. if you arrived in the US with a permanent immigrant visa).

Comment: We need your visa status and your income from outside the USA to have any way to answer this.  US residents are taxed on worldwide income, not just US income.  (However, you get a credit for taxes paid to other countries--the net effect is you are taxed at higher of the two rates, not double taxed.)